# Problems with SAS after applying Fix Pack 8 to DB2

Tags: sas, db2, db2-luw

We use DB2 (v. 10.5) to store our data. After we had applied Fix Pack 8 to database (client and JDBC driver had been also updated) we faced the following problems:

1)  SAS EG didn’t show tables in DB2 libraries;
2)  SAS Content Server couldn’t start with the following error in log:

```
INFO  2017-02-09 14:08:50,541 [server.startup : 1] - Starting repository...
ERROR 2017-02-09 14:08:50,811 [server.startup : 1] - failed to initialize file system
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-443, SQLSTATE=38553, SQLERRMC=SYSIBM.SQLTABLES;TABLES;SYSIBM:CLI:-514, DRIVER=3.67.27
     at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gd.a(gd.java:752)
```

As recommended here (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21369762) for similar cases we executed the following commands in DB2:

```
db2 connect to <databasename> 
db2 bind db2schema.bnd blocking all grant public sqlerror continue 
db2 terminate
```

But it has not solved the issues.

What could we forget to do?
How could we try to solve the issue or reveal its root?

Our version of SAS is 9.3. Server OS is AIX, client OS is Windows.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on dba.stackexchange.com and has indeed a duplicate there: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/164084/error-sqlcode-443-sqlstate-38553-after-applying-fix-pack-8-to-db2-v10-5

Comment: OK, I agree with you.